# Internet Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: networking

I'm running 16.04 on my laptop and it says I'm connected but whenever I pull up a webpage it says

```
DNS address could not be found

Try
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
```

It was working fine a couple of days ago.

This happens on Firefox and Chrome.

This does not happen if I boot a live copy of Ubuntu on the same laptop and connect to the same network.

I've tried deleting and re-adding the network in Edit Connections but the problem persists.

**Additional Info:**

This is a WiFi connection

In System Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy it says Method: None

`nslookup google.com` returned `connection timed out`

`ping 8.8.8.8` had 0% packet loss

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:6b:23:b7:8b:1e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e4400000-e4420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:7649 (7.6 KB)  TX bytes:7649 (7.6 KB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b6:76:e9:2b:77  
          inet addr:10.0.0.49  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4200:b0f0::a567/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4200:b0f0:980d:2093:a87:e2c8/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4200:b0f0:945f:1cf3:cbda:5021/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c63:2a6e:4d93:9edb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:818172 (818.1 KB)  TX bytes:547880 (547.8 KB)
```

Comment: Are you connecting via WiFi or ethernet?  Are you using DHCP?  Do you have a system-wide proxy set up in System Settings > Network?  Do you have a proxy set up in Firefox?  What might have changed since things worked a couple days ago?  Please edit your question to give us more information.

Comment: post results of `ifconfig -a` `nslookup google.com` `ping 8.8.8.8` when things are not working

Comment: rclocher, if my post was too long I would have never recieved any replies. I tried to provide the most relevant information. Sorry I meant to mention it's wifi. It says None in Network proxy. I do not know what changed, from what I recall this happened randomly.

Comment: meccooll, nslookup failed, ping had 0% loss. Is there any specific info you need from ifconfig? I can't copy and paste the results because I have no internet on my laptop.

Comment: Boot normally copy and paste output to file and save it. Then reboot with live, open saved file and copy and paste it into your question its a  pain but the only way.

Comment: @NugU, thanks for the cooperation!  Try changing your WiFi IPv4 connection settings so that you're using `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only`, and then set your DNS server to be 8.8.8.8, which is a Google public DNS server.  Also, when replying to someone please put @ before his or her user name, so that he or she will be notified.  Otherwise we have to manually go back and check.

Comment: @rclocher3 Thanks. I came to work and when I got here my internet was working again. I wonder if it will stop working when I go back home. If it does I will try your suggestions.

Comment: @rclocher3 When I got home my internet was working again and then after a couple of days it stopped working again. I tried your suggestion but it didn't fix the problem. I have Automatic (DHCP) addresses only selected and below that I have 8.8.8.8 for my DNS. I can still ping 8.8.8.8 but my browser says server DNS address could not be found whenever I load a web page.

Comment: Is there any way to bump my thread? Every time I ask a question my thread just dies and I never get an answer... :(

Comment: @NugU I've given you lots of help, so please don't complain about it!  Believe you me, there are lots more people needing help than sympathetic people willing to help for free.  So please edit your question to show the output of `nmcli device show wlp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS`.  Editing your question will "bump" it.  BTW this isn't a forum-style site; we're trying to make a high-quality collection of questions with answers.  Take [the tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn more.

Comment: @rclocher3 It returned `IP4.DNS[1]: 8.8.8.8`. That's what I set it to. I have been out of town with no Ubuntu disk so I couldn't reply until just barely. I also wasn't able to get any WiFi while I was out of town. I'm going to remove and readd the connection and if it doesn't work I'll probably just reformat. I confirmed the WiFi is working in a live boot so a reinstall will probably fix it.

Comment: @rclocher3 Interestingly my computer notified me of updates when I turned it on. It needs internet to do that, right? However, chrome and firefox are still giving me the same issue when I try to open a web page.

Comment: @NugU Interesting...  What happens when you do `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @rclocher3 0% loss, still no web pages loading. I've got everything backed up but I'll wait til tomorrow to reformat in case there's anything else you want me to check

Comment: @NugU Try `nslookup google.com`.

Comment: @rclocher3 I got `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` but I can still ping 8.8.8.8. I removed and readded the connection earlier though so I went in and changed to `Automatic DHCP (addresses only)` and added 8.8.8.8 as a DNS server but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Wow @NugU, I'm stumped.  Your problem seems to be DNS-related.  You have 8.8.8.8 as your only DNS server, and you can ping it, but it doesn't return DNS queries.  The only thing I can think of is that some firewall is blocking DNS queries, but who would set up a firewall like that?

Comment: @rclocher3 Idk. It's not a firewall on the router because other devices and live boot work fine. Must be related to the OS settings or drivers or something. I'll just reinstall. This case remains cold for now